# How to define json string in yaml under "x-additionalInfo"

Tags: json, yaml

i am trying some additional info to be passed in yaml. 
json is the additional data and using mustache template i am getting that data and doing the parsing.
json data defined in yaml is received in mustache template file as shown below

**"{inputMapping=[{"name":"exchangeratetype"}]".**

How to pass a json in yaml?Do i encode to some format and then define in yaml?

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use like a following ways described in this link on

*24.6 Using YAML Instead of Properties*

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf

in your case the format will be:

```
inputMapping:
  -
    name: exchangeratetype1
  -
    name: exchangeratetype2
```

Comment: i need to use these json inside mustache template to generate a java file containing the json  as String inputMapping= "{\"fromAmount\":\"amount\"}";